# Run ksh command from java code to run script file

Tags: java, processbuilder

I am trying to execute a script file at *(location : /home/id/scripts/)* from my java code. Below is my java code :

```
Process process = null;
scriptfileName = "myScript.sh" ;
executeCmd = "/home/id/scripts/" +scriptfileName ;  
process = new ProcessBuilder(executeCmd).start();
```

When I try to run the script using above code, only initial some lines are getting executed like, I placed 2 echo statement, only the first one is getting printed and rest below lines which has update DataBase statements are not executing. Same script file if I am running directly using command - `{ksh sctiptfileName}`, it successfully executes and updates DB.

Comment: What are those statements which do not get executed?

Comment: How are you checking the output? Database scripts will write to STDOUT and STDERR

Comment: In the below lines i am setting the data base name and password and some select and update statements .  Example :

Comment: In the below lines i am setting the data base name and password and some select and update statements .

Comment: In the below lines i am setting the data base name and password and some select and update statements .      Ex.   mkdir logs
echo "begin executing script ...."
cat << EOF  isql -UDB -SDBserver -Ppassword | tee 11111.log
use db
go
set rowcount 30
go
print "Before Update ....."
go
select statement
go
print "Updating ....".
go
update statemet
go

EOF
echo "End of script ...."                                       (script prints only "begin executing script ...."  and does not create the "logs" folder in the directly of the script .. )